# How to detect browser refresh alone

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to detect browser refresh alone in javascript. The below code am using is detecting the browser close as well as refresh, back etc.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
      var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
      console.log(evt);
      console.log(window.event);
      console.log(event);
      if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
      }
      if (evt) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
      }
      return evt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the current time to session storage from `onbeforeunload`, then when the page loads look in session storage for a time and, if you find one and it's within (say) a couple of seconds, assume it's a refresh.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("left", Date.now());
};
```

and elsewhere, in code that runs when the page loads:

```
var left = sessionStorage.getItem("left");
if (left && (Date.now() - left) < 2000) {
    // Refreshed
}
```

Full example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/tihizajebe)):

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("left", Date.now());
    };

    var left = sessionStorage.getItem("left");
    if (left && (Date.now() - left) < 2000) {
        // Refreshed
        display("Refreshed");
    } else {
        // Freshly loaded
    }
})();
```

Comment: But this is getting reflected in browser close as well, how to control it?

Comment: @Ajith: Again: The code that runs when the page loads looks for the value set by the `onbeforeunload` code, and if the value is within a couple of seconds of "now," it's a refresh.

Comment: Hi Crowder this is working fine for refresh, Is there any code to detect browser close alone.Thanks for help

Comment: @Ajith: Not that I'm aware of.